# django python slug variable in models.py

Tags: python, django

While I hit the search button..it shows the

Page not found (404)

No Category matches the given query.

**My views**

```
def search_in_category(request, slug):
# reset the search params, if present

try:
    del request.session['search']
except KeyError:
   pass
return search_results(request, slug)

def search_results(request, slug):
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
fields = list(category.field_set.all())
fields += list(Field.objects.filter(category=None))
fieldsLeft = [field.name for field in fields]

if request.method == "POST" or 'search' in request.session:
    ads = category.ad_set.filter(active=True,
                                 expires_on__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
    # A request dictionary with keys defined for all
    # fields in the category.
    post = {}
    if 'search' in request.session:
        post.update(request.session['search'])
    else:
        post.update(request.POST)

    sforms = prepare_sforms(fields, fieldsLeft, post)

    isValid = True

    for f in sforms:
        # TODO: this assumes the form is not required
        # (it's a search form after all)
        if not f.is_valid() and not f.is_empty():
            isValid = False

    if isValid:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            request.session['search'] = {}
            request.session['search'].update(request.POST)
            return redirect('classifieds_browse_search_results', slug=slug)

        for f in sforms:
            ads = f.filter(ads)

        if ads.count() == 0:
            return render_to_response('classifieds/list.html',
                                      {'no_results': True,
                                       'category': category},
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            context = context_sortable(request, ads)
            context['category'] = category
            return render_to_response('classifieds/list.html', context,
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    sforms = prepare_sforms(fields, fieldsLeft)

return render_to_response('classifieds/search.html',
                          {'forms': sforms, 'category': category},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**My models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
template_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
slug = models.SlugField()
enable_contact_form_upload = models.BooleanField(default=False)
contact_form_upload_max_size = models.IntegerField(default=2 ** 20)
contact_form_upload_file_extensions = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                                 default="txt,doc,odf,pdf")
images_max_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
images_max_width = models.IntegerField(help_text=_(u'Maximum width in pixels.'),
                                       default=1024)
images_max_height = models.IntegerField(help_text=_(u'Maximum height in pixels.'),
                                        default=1024)
images_max_size = models.IntegerField(help_text=_(u'Maximum size in bytes.'),
                                      default=2 ** 20)
images_allowed_formats = models.ManyToManyField(ImageFormat, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(default='')
sortby_fields = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                 help_text=_(u'A comma separated list of field names that should show up as sorting options.'),
                                 blank=True)
sort_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name + u' Category'

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = u'categories'
```

**My url**

```
url(r'^search/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'browse.search_in_category',
    name='classifieds_browse_category_search'),

url(r'^search/results/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'browse.search_results',
    name='classifieds_browse_search_results'),
```

This my code, Why I am getting the 404 error? What I have to do for fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do

```
return search_results(request, slug)
```

do rather this redirect

```
return redirect(reverse('classifieds_browse_search_results', kwargs={'slug':slug}))
```

dont forget to import

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

Comment: Ya i changed your code..but again it throws that same page not found  error while i hit the search anchor link.

Comment: ``print slug`` before the line ``return search_results(request, slug)`` and tell me what it is ;) @Geetha

Comment: @Geetha what is shown in console? print does not come in browser!

Comment: ya ya i checked in console too...Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[01/Dec/2014 12:45:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1925
[01/Dec/2014 12:45:19] "GET /search/bike/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2233
[01/Dec/2014 12:45:27] "POST /search/bike/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[01/Dec/2014 12:45:27] "GET /search/results/bike/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1947
[01/Dec/2014 12:45:28] "GET /search/2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1615

Comment: @geetha, is your slug really there? Make sure that slug is during redirect there.

Comment: @geetha, btw /search/2/ doesnot work since slug is "word" regexp and not number

Comment: sorry cant understand..so what i have to do??

Comment: @Geetha you cannot give ``2`` as your slug, because its number. so change your urlregexp from ``(?P<slug>[-\w]+)`` to ``(?P<slug>[^\/]*)`` then it will work

Comment: url(r'^search/(?P<slug>[^\/]*)/$', 'browse.search_in_category',
        name='classifieds_browse_category_search'),
                            
    url(r'^search/results/(?P<slug>[^\/]*)/$', 'browse.search_results',
        name='classifieds_browse_search_results'),      i gave like this..but again error.

Comment: just accept my answer so that your reputation goes up, then we can chat here. with your reputation now, you cannot chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65941/discussion-between-doniyor-and-geetha).